# Build sibling projects when running mvn install

Tags: maven, mvn-repo

We have a project that recently switched from ant and crappy CLI tools to maven,
our current structure is:

```
- parent
    - main-project:
    - sub-module-A:
    - sub-module-B:
```

Each one of these projects is in it's own repository and they are linked through pom files 
parent has all three projects defined in  tags and main-project defines both sub modules as dependencies.

**the issue at hand:**

Since main-project is where I deploy the site (in this case) I want to make sure that the sources of both modules are updated when I run it which means I want to compile if needed both sub modules when I run `mvn install` on the main-project.

I tried using mvn-exec-plugin to build both but it's not actually building anything.

Any idea how to fix this?

***edit:*** I am running `mvn appengine:run` from `main-project` and want the sources from sub-modules A and B to install if needed

Comment: Are you executing the `site` phase in the Maven command, e.g. `mvn install site`?

Comment: executing `appengine:run`

Comment: `appengine:run` is what Maven calls a goal, where `install` and `site` are phases. Phases can be configured to run multiple goals in a specific order. You may need to figure out how to tie the `appengine:run` into the app's POM so it runs at the proper point in the larger phase, or perhaps run multiple Maven commands (e.g. `mvn appengine:run site`). Google 'maven lifecycle' for more detail, the docs are decent. I don't know enough about the appengine plugin to provide more guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `main-project` has dependencies on `sub-module-A` and `sub-module-B` and the parent has all projects as modules, i. e.

**parent**

```
<modules>
    <module>main-project</module>
    <module>sub-module-A</module>
    <module>sub-module-B</module>
<modules>
```

**main-project**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>sub-module-A</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>sub-module-B</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then, you can build the `parent` project with

```
mvn --projects :main-project --also-make install
```

or using shortcuts for the options

```
mvn -pl :main-project -am install
```

With these options only the `main-project` and all its dependencies (which are somewhere in the `parent`'s modules) are built.

See [this](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/_using_advanced_reactor_options.html#_specifying_a_subset_of_projects) and [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) for more information.

Comment: question is can I run `appengine:run` from `main-project` *and* install sub-modules A and B?